# Getting screen height returns a larger screen than the physical screen can display

Tags: java, android, screen, titlebar

When I get the screen size for my Android app, it returns a variable which in every case is too large for the screen to display. I use the following code to get screen size.

```
final int windowHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
final int windowWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Is there any way to compensate for it? Or to even fix my problem?

Also, is there a way to turn the battery/time bar off in the app? I think that might be the reason I'm having trouble, but I don't actually know. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the battery/time bar, I use this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, for the `<application>` tag :

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
    ...
    >
```

And, to get the screen's size, here's what I have in my `Activity` :

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: my view is coded in so i cant use the XML stuff, i will check developer.android though

Comment: Even if your view is coded *(and done using XML)*, you still have the `<application>` tag in your manifest, don't you ? *(but I have to admit that, if you only want one view to be full-screen, and not the whole application, ... still, there might be some way of getting the same result in code)*

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you might want density points instead of pixels. 
If you get the dimensions in pixels here's how you convert them. But you can get the dimensions in dp too

```
        /*  
         * Get dps from pixel.
         */
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        public static float dpFromPixels(int pixels) {
            float dp = (float) (pixels / scale + 0.5f);
            return dp;
        }
```

Comment: unfortunatly the dp isnt what im looking for in my app. but thankyou for you answer, this will come in ver handy in the future